# centrar texto en imagen php

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de alinear al centro la descripcion de unos productos que traigo de una base de datos, loc ual luego es impreso en un ticket. 
La cadena que traigo es variable, puede tener desde 10 hasta 200 caracteres, por lo cual debo guardar el dato en una cadena, y formatearla para pasarla a impresión en 1 ó mas líneas.
He intentado con str_pad, pero como la fuente no es monoespacio no funciona en la mayoría de las veces, se visaulizan grandes diferencias.
Estuve estudiando la documentación de php pero no entiendo del todo o no le encuentro al vuelta.
El código que uso :

```html
<?php
Header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreate(400,300);
$fondo=imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 110);
$gris=imagecolorallocate ($im, 160, 160,160);
$negro=imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);
$texto="Estosos dsdwsvwes rbbuna rbprueba de impresio Esto esrbbrrbr una prueba de impresiorbrr Esto es una prueba de impresion";
$lines1 = explode('|', wordwrap($texto, 28, '|'));
$y=150;
 foreach ($lines1 as $line1) {
          {
           $line1=trim($line1);
              $line1 = str_pad($line1, 30,"0", STR_PAD_BOTH);
              $marco= ImageTTFBBox (24, 0, "arial.ttf", $line1);
     $x = abs(ceil(400 - ($marco[2]-$marco[0])));
     $y += 30;              
     Imagettftext($im, 14, 0, $x, $y, $negro,"arial.ttf", $line1);
          }  
  }

Imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Alguna ayuda para lograr alinear la variable $texto ?

Gracias !!

Comment: estas seguro que lo tienes que hacer con php?

Comment: te respondí en tu otra pregunta. Y ojo, estás midiendo el bbox con tamaño 24 e imprimiendo con tamaño 14. Eso nunca va a funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fijate con las correcciones que hice te centra bien los textos, espero sea lo que estabas necesitando.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreate(400,300);
$fondo=imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 110);
$gris=imagecolorallocate ($im, 160, 160,160);
$negro=imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);
$texto="Estosos dsdwsvwes rbbuna rbprueba de impresio Esto esrbbrrbr una prueba de impresiorbrr Esto es una prueba de impresion";
$lines1 = explode('|', wordwrap($texto, 28, '|'));
$y=150;
    foreach ($lines1 as $line1) {
                {
                    $line1=trim($line1);
                    //$line1 = str_pad($line1, 30,"0", STR_PAD_BOTH);
                    $marco= ImageTTFBBox (14, 0, "arial.ttf", $line1);
                    $x = (400 - ($marco[2]-$marco[0])) / 2;
                    $y += 30;                   
                    Imagettftext($im, 14, 0, $x, $y, $negro,"arial", $line1);
                }       
        }

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Si lo que querías era centrar las lineas tenias un error en la formula de la coordenada X y el str_pad no es necesario.

Comment: hola amigo usando tu código da el error de que no se puede visualizar la imagen por que contiene errores